# 'On the fly' unpackaging of files on Android

Tags: java, android, packaging

I need to package a few files (total upto 4 GB in size) which will be available online. An android app needs to download this 'on the fly' without saving the archive on to the device. So basically the device won't save the archive and then unpack, as it would require double the space. Which package format should I choose that will support it (eg. zip, tar.gz etc.)?

Comment: but what will be diffance betwenn 2 types? u can use any

Comment: Usually its download the archive, extract and then delete the archive. This requires double the space. So need a solution so that the package is extracted incrementally.

Comment: but still unclear , what u want to not happen?

Comment: The question really comes down to asking which compression schemes can be unpacked without needing to store a large amount of reference data from elsewhere in the stream.  One that needs things like dictionary references that could be many megabytes away from the data currently being processed would be a bad fit.  Similarly, one that put the table of contents somewhere other than the beginning (or at least preceding the data it indexes) would be a bad fit.

Answer (score 1):

Use .zip! You can use `ZipInputStream` and `ZipOutputStream` to read and write from .zip files on the fly. No need to extract the files from the archive.

[**Link to documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)

---

And here is a quick example:

```
InputStream is =...
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
try {

    // ZipEntry contains data about files and folders in the archive.
    ZipEntry ze; 

    // This loops through the whole content of the archive
    while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        // Here we read the whole data of one ZipEntry
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        // The ZipEntry contains data about the file, like its filename
        String filename = ze.getName();

        // And that's the file itself as byte array
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

        // Do something with the file            
    }
} finally {
    zis.close();
}
```